# Проблема с вычислением

Tags: python

Есть проблема. Надо в 33 строке посчитать формулу, но у меня не получается. Ошибка. Что делать?

```
import math
import time
print('Программа работает с геометрической прогрессией')
time.sleep(2)
print('Прежде чем мы начнем, напишите, Вы знаете второй член прогресии b2 (Да/Нет): ')
answer=input()
if answer == 'Да':
    print('Введите первый член прогресии (!= 0): ')
    b1 = input()
    print('Введите второй член прогресии (!= 0): ')
    b2 = input()
    q = eval(b2) / eval(b1)
elif answer == 'Нет':
    print('Введите первый член прогресии (!= 0): ')
    b1 = input()
    print('Введите знаменатель прогресии (!= 0): ')
    q = input()
    b2 = eval(b1) * eval(q)
else:
    print('Ошибка ввода. Работа программы прекращена.')
    time.sleep(3)
    exit(0)


print()
print('Отлично. Теперь у нас есть всё, для того чтобы поработать с прогрессией!')
print('Bn: b1 = '+str(b1)+'; b2 = '+str(b2)+'; q = '+str(q))
print()
time.sleep(1)
print('Давайте найдем какой-нибудь член этой прогресии.')
print('Введите номер члена, который будем искать: ')
n=input()
bn=b1 * (q ** n-1)
print(bn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> у меня не получается. Ошибка. Что делать?

Как Вы считаете, нам было бы легче ответить на Ваш вопрос, если бы мы знали, какая это ошибка?

---

Какой здесь приоритет операций, и какие типы переменных?

```
bn = float(b1) * (float(q) ** (int(n) - 1))
```

Comment: Да, Ваш приоритет правильный. Но все равно не работает =(  :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Да, теперь всё работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @РоманРатушный Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.